# Unable to update variables outside node module

Tags: node.js

In below code I am trying to update x value based on the db results, but with the below code x value is not updating

its returning 0 instead of 3
Below is the endpoint I am trying but, its getting errored as TypeError: Cannot set property 'hasaccess' of undefined

code:

```
  app.get("/app/searchusers", (req, res) => {
    headr = req.headers;
    let skey = headr["skey"];
    let uid = headr["uid"];
    let strm = headr["sterm"];
    var sql2 ='SELECT fname, lname, username, ? as hasaccess,? as error from USER_INFO where mobile = ? or email like ? or fname like ? or lname like ?';
    var sql3 =
      "SELECT COUNT(p_username) as resm from USERACCESS_INFO where p_username=? and g_username=?";
    var params1 = [uid, skey];
    var params2 = [false, "false", strm, strm + "%", strm + "%", strm + "%"];
    db.all(sql2, params2, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.send([
          {
            fname: null,
            lname: null,
            hasaccess: null,
            username: null,
            error: true,
          },
        ]);
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var params3 = [uid, results[i].username];
          db.all(sql3, params3, (err, result3, fields) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("err");
              return res.send([
                {
                  fname: null,
                  lname: null,
                  hasaccess: null,
                  username: null,
                  error: true,
                },
              ]);
            } else {
              console.log("inner : "+ result3[0].resm);
              results[i].hasaccess =result3[0].resm;
            }
          });
        }
        return res.send(results);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: else block must not be executed. that could be the only reason.
put some logging in if block

Comment: are you sure `err` is not set? Have you tried printing it? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: It returns before db.all is finished.

Comment: need help on how to get the updated results